# How can we match the length of the Gregorian year and the length of the tropical year?

Tags: gregorian-calendar, leap-year

At present the average length of the Gregorian Year over a period of 400 years is 365.2425 days, calculated as follows.
Average length of the Gregorian Year =  (97 x 366 + 303 x 365)/ 400 = 365.2425 days
Since the length of the Tropical year is 365 days 5 hours 48 minutes 46 seconds that is, 365 + 20926/8640 = 365.24219907 days, due to which, there is a gap of 0.0003093 day per year, say 0.00031 day per year in them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all difficult to bridge even this gap, by shedding one more leap year over a period of 3226 years, calculated in the following manner.
Supposing it has to be shed over N years — we can, very easily, calculate the value of N, as follows.
N = 1/0.00031 = 3225.8 years, say, 3226 years.
Since it has already covered 438 years since the year 1582 AD obviously, we can synchronise both years by shedding one more leap year over the next “3226 – 438” years, that is, by October 5, 4808.
I would recommend that the International Astronomical Society may take cognisance of this possibility.